# When is omitting await acceptable in asynchronous functions?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

As far as I understand it, the `await` keyword prevents a function from continuing until the called asynchronous function completes. Essentially, it makes the asynchronous function synchronous. So that the following holds:

```cs
await MyAsyncMethod();      // first this is called
await MyOtherAsyncMethod(); // only when the above completes, this is called 
MyNonAsyncMethod();         // similarly, this is only called when the above completes
```

Now in most code editors, omitting the `await` keyword results in a warning. This is baffling to me given my understanding of what `async` is supposed to accomplish. For if we await every asynchronous method, are we not thereby making them all synchronous, and thus defeating the very purpose of asynchronous programming?

For example, in my specific use-case, I have a function that saves a blogpost to a database, and emails all of the blog's subscribers to notify them that a new post has been created. From the perspective of the user that creates the blogpost, it is pointless to wait for the result of the mailing. The mailing logic is a simple `for` loop that just sends emails out to the subscribers and returns no information worth considering. The user only cares that the blogpost has been created, and that the mailing logic has initiated, and he wants to receive this information promptly. I have therefore left out the `await` keyword and have allowed the process to continue in the background, while returning to the user a value that indicates that all is OK.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Blogpost blogpost)
{
  try 
  {
     // save to db
     await CreateBlogPostAsync(blogpost);
     // initiate mailing logic
     NotifySubscribersAsync();

     return Ok(blogpost);
  }
  catch
  {
    // return error code
    return StatusCode(500);
  }
}
```

This works perfectly for my use-case. I don't want the user to have to wait a long time for the sending process to complete before he receives an OK signal. I thought that this is precisely what asynchronous programming was meant to accomplish: allowing processes to happen in the background while the function continues. Yet, though the code compiles and runs alright for my purposes, VSCode warns me that I should be using the await keyword.

What is it I am not understanding here?

Comment: That might cause threadpool starvation under load.

Comment: *Essentially, it makes the asynchronous function synchronous* It doesn't. Possibly you don't quite got the idea of what `await` does. In short, omitting `await` means that 1) exceptions are possibly ignored (there's no one to catch them) 2) the DI container disposes things at the end of request but the pending task is still executing in the background, resulting in a possible non-deterministic exception

Comment: *"For if we await every asynchronous method, are we not thereby making them all synchronous, and thus defeating the very purpose of asynchronous programming?"* - No.  The calling code can still treat the operation asynchronously.  All the way up to the application host and/or UI which can free up the thread to do other things while this operation executes asynchronously.

Comment: @JonasH I'm not sure how I'm lying. The function for saving to DB is awaited. The only way it would return OK is if the blogpost was published to the database. However, I have chosen not to await the function that sends emails to subscribers, as that would (1) take a long time to complete depending upon subscriber count, and (2) is uninteresting information with which very little can be done.

Comment: One potential issue is that the `NotifySubscribersAsync` starts in the request scope but since it isn't awaited, the scope may be disposed before the method completes. If the implementation depends on some scoped service or request-related property (e.g. via HttpContext), they may sometimes work and other times fail due to the concurrency. The solution is to only enqueue the operation (synchronously or asynchronously with await) and execute it in separate context.

Comment: @rexinvictus I apologize, I was a bit quick at reading the question. Yes, if you await `CreateBlogPostAsync`, and that is the only part the user cares about, then it might make sense to not await `NotifySubscribersAsync`. But you still need to ensure that `NotifySubscribersAsync` is safe, and that errors are handled appropriately. If you have done that you can ignore the compiler warning, I have a `.Ignore()` extension method to show that the task is explicitly fire-and-forget.

Comment: *warns me that I should be using the await keyword* - actually, it doesn't. It says "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the await operator to the result of the call". This is subtly, but vitally, different from "you should await this call"

Comment: *What is it I am not understanding here?* - show us the definition of NotifySubscribersAsync for more advice. If it uses components that were injected into this class by DI, maybe one day it'll just start failing, and people won't get their notifications because the injector will dispose the things that send the notifications before they have a chance to send them.. And as people have said, this will be quite a tedious thing to debug because you'll be looking at an ObjectDisposedException miles away from where the problem actually is, if it's even logged at all

Comment: If you want to suppress the warning, you can simply assign the returned task to the discard `_ = NotifySubscribersAsync()` which is sufficient enough a declaration to the compiler of "I know what I'm doing and I have deliberately chosen not to await this task". It doesn't banish any of the other dragons therein be

Comment: @flackoverstow NotifySubscribersAsync takes a list of Subscriber objects and sends an email to them all individually with a for loop (using an email service). If there is an error it continues to the next subscriber until it exhausts them all. The code I showed you was trimmed for simplicity: in the original, the Create function makes a request to db for the entire list of subscribers then calls NotifySubscribersAsync with the list of subscribers passed in as an argument.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't ask for a story about it; I asked for the code of it. Sounds like it has a long job to do which makes it even more likely the injector will chuck it away before it's done! Perhaps instead of a queue system you should just decouple your email sending from your system here - have a separate worker that goes looking for posts in an Unnotified state and sends the emails as a separate action, time delayed, not impacting the UX here

Comment: @flackoverstow I admit I am much too uninformed to understand what you're talking about -- why the "injector" would "chuck it away", for instance. The function seems to be self-sufficient when it's called, possessing all it needs to run on its own, so I'm not sure what you mean by "it uses components that were injected into this class by DI". Perhaps I will bull-headedly charge along with my current implementation and take any future errors as a lesson. In any case, I don't see the point in showing you the code for that function, since it is rather simple and does exactly what I described.

Comment: An operation is syncronous or its asyncronous. "Await" simply means one "needs" to know the results of an async op. Returning void from an async op accomplishes the same thing (it makes Await redundant). You can still indirectly depend on an async op; e.g. loading a datasource in the background ... noting that some controls (e.g. Image) can do their own async loading; particularly in UWP apps. You trigger the process via the assignment of a URL to the image source.

Comment: @rexinvictus *why the "injector" would "chuck it away", for instance* - because that's what the injector does, what it's supposed to do.. Your code in `CreateBlogPostAsync` probably uses an entity framework context that "magically" arrived in the constructor of this class as a passed-in instance of a thing that manipulates a DB, already set up and ready to go. That was perhaps created by the dependency injector at the start of processing the current web request, or some shorter lifetime, and it will be thrown away when the request is over/lifetime expires..

Comment: I don't mind if you don't show any more than this curt example, but you did specifically ask when it is acceptable to omit await; without showing us the full depth of what is awaitable/what long operations you do we can't really offer much comment on whether any of it is omissible - we can only try to educate you as to some possible the consequences and then leave you to decide for your own code. Whether you'll make the right decision is hard to say, because you might end up with a little knowledge being a dangerous thing

Answer (score 2):

> From the perspective of the user that creates the blogpost, it is pointless to wait for the result of the mailing.

Omitting `await` is the wrong way to do that.  The operations that the user is waiting for are:

- Write to the DB
- Queue the notifications

The first one can easily be `async` as data access libraries commonly support that.  The latter depends on how you queue the notifications.

If you treat that notifications process as "fire and forget" then the problem is the "forget" part.  What if it fails?  Nothing is observing that result, so nothing will know it failed.

On the other hand, instead of sending the notifications immediately and ignoring the result, do something which simply *queues* the notifications and immediately returns control.  This could be putting a message on a message queue somewhere, it could be writing a record to a database, etc.  These can easily be `async` operations that finish quickly and return to the user.

Then a separate application would be monitoring that message queue, database table, etc. to observe the queued process, and would begin that logic.  *That* application *does* want to wait for the result of the mailing, observing if each operations succeeds or fails.

Basically, the example you're using isn't *really* related to `async`.  It's *asynchronous* in the sense that a separate process handles the heavy lifting while the user continues whatever they're doing.  But it's not using `async` and `await` for that.

---

It's often good to intuitively separate "asynchronous" from `async`.  The latter is a subset of the former, but lots of things are "asynchronous" that have nothing to do with `async`.

Asynchronous operations can vary significantly.  Maybe they use `async`, maybe they use callbacks, maybe they use entirely separate processes/applications, etc., etc.

But `async` and `await` in the vast majority of cases are much simpler than that.  They're *mostly* used when you have an otherwise semantically synchronous operation which under the hood relies on hardware that can perform the operation without the CPU waiting for it.  Network access, disk access, DB access, etc.

`async` and `await` are the tools the code uses to indicate this, and to allow the application to still be responsive to input while waiting for other hardware to return information.  Common examples include not blocking a UI thread in a desktop application so it can still respond to clicks while performing a heavy operation, or allowing a web server to re-use threads and continue to handle incoming requests while some users wait for heavy operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation, especially about the distinction between async and asynchronous. As I have read in another answer, though, apparently one can return void from an asynchronous function if one does not care about observing its errors, which seems appropriate for my use-case. What would be the advantages of the queue system you proposed over this, given that your method adds complexity? For if I truly do not care about the errors it may possibly encounter (since I will not be re-sending the notifications and can infer errors from my email's outbox), why not return void?

Comment: @rexinvictus: If you *truly do not care* if the process succeeds or fails then you can simply omit `await`, sure.  (Though in my experience *every time* that has come up, at some point later that same developer comes back with a problem about something failing and they can't find the cause.  So just be aware of what you're proposing.)  In that case you certainly *can* return `void`, but I'd really avoid it where possible.  `async void` is really only supported at all for backward compatability of event handler methods.  Personally I'd opt for a compiler directive to suppress the warning.

Comment: @rexinvictus: Basically, with regards to `async void`, "I don't want to await this operation here" is very, very different from "I don't want anybody to ever be able to await or observe the result of this operation at any point ever."  The latter is a bit more restrictive to the system without much real benefit.  (It also signals to other developers on the team that `async void` is okay, which can lead to a great many problems.)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. If (being conscious of your time) I may ask one more question, I would like some further clarification on precisely why you anticipate problems resulting from the omission of await, and why you are so confident that such problems will prove inevitable? The answer to this question will help me decide whether to follow your suggestion and create a queuing system, or to continue on the more controversial path of omitting await.

Comment: @rexinvictus: It's just from experience, not a guarantee.  I've often heard developers claim they want to "fire and forget" an operation for better performance.  Then sometime later that operation starts to fail and cause problems.  Then that same developer, or someone else on the team, is left trying to debug something that was *intentionally* left not observing its own result.  It's possible this isn't the case here, it's just very common in my experience.  Being explicit is generally better than hiding information.  A compiler directive (with a comment) is explicit and clear to readers.

Answer (score 0):

So what is the point of awaiting something. The main idea of asynchronous programming is to have a blocking task like IO run in the background, as to not block the main thread and keep your application specific.

Why does Visual Studio Code tell you to await your function call

Well, because most of the time you may want the task to run in the background, but the lines below your function call may depend on the function completing first.

That is the default assumption when your function returns a task.

If you wan't to just call your function and don't care about it's return change it's return type to void. If you do so Visual Studio Code should not bother you.

Comment: Your IO shouldn't be blocking.  That `await` is in the conversation means it's properly asynchronous and thus *isn't* blocking.  Running synchronous IO in a background thread is what people often did *before `await` existed* and what it's specifically designed to prevent from happening.  For performing long running IO *there's no need for a background thread at all* and `await` makes accomplishing that easier than before it existed.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought async functions had to return a Task to be async. If I return void would it still run asynchronously?

Comment: Yes you would still run asynchronously. You're just making clear that you don't care about the result. However that also means you won't know if something fails.

Comment: *"If you wan't to just call your function and don't care about it's return change it's return type to void."* - **Not if the method is `async`**.  The correct way to "return nothing" from an `async` method is for the return type to be `Task`.  If consuming code truly has a reason not to `await`  the operation (which the example given isn't really a great example of) then consuming code can suppress the warning with a compiler directive.  Breaking the method itself is the wrong approach.

Comment: @David If one particular caller doesn't need to know about the result, they ignore the task, if *no caller would ever need to know when or if it finishes*, then it should be `void`.  Of course, the former is much more common than the latter, but both should be rarely used.

Comment: *Why does Visual Studio Code tell you to await your function call* - it doesn't tell you to await it; it warns you that you haven't awaited it. That's not a hair split, that's a key difference